# Failure installing openMPI (or spinningup) in python 3.6, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-16.04, openmpi

Im trying out the spinning-up tutorial on deep-RL and have been dealing several hours solving this problem (unsuccessfully).

here is what I did before the failure:

```
$ conda create -n spinningup python=3.6    
$ source activate spinningup

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev    
$ git clone https://github.com/openai/spinningup.git    
$ cd spinningup    
$ pip install -e .
```

I have very little experience with linux, so the solution could be trivial. The first error message I encounter is:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mpi4py
Building wheel for mpi4py (setup.py) ... error
```

and later:

```
error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for mpi4py
```

Comment: Can you insert the output from `sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev`? My educated guess from the error message would be that you are missing a C/C++ compiler or `mpicc` (the MPI compiler wrapper) doesn't work for some other reason. You probably want to follow the [mpi4py installation instructions](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) to make sure it can be installed on your system.

Comment: It somehow worked after I did "sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev". Thanks alot!